# 1 socket - send and recv in different threads

Tags: windows, multithreading, sockets, communication

I got stuck at designing/logic stage right now. I have a client that runs 2 threads and is using 1 socket which is connected to the server.

In main thread there are GUI operations and when user click X on program's title bar then program sends CLOSE packet to server and server removes cleint from users list - that works without problems.

Problems came when I added option which allows manually removing users from server by person who run server. When admin right click user he can kick him -> then server send CLOSE packet to client and that  works but here is the catch:

Client uses as I said 2 threads in one thread he send CLOSE packet and in other he waits for it in different threads (blocking) - that thread is launched ebfore even showing the window.

So we here is problematic situtation:

Client joins the server and wants to leave it - won't work because second thread of client side is already blocking socket and first thread can't send CLOSE packet.

Any ideas how to nice resolve it?

EDIT: Now I am not sure if it's problem with that because sometimes it works and sometimes first thread doesn't send data or server doesn't recv.

Anyway I have also just read that recv and send on one socket from different threads should not be the problem so I am confused.

Comment: If you're using TCP connections, there is no need to send a CLOSE packet; you can simply close the local end of the TCP connection and the other end will be notified that the connection is closed (which is a case you'll need to handle anyway, since the TCP connection can be closed "spontaneously" e.g. by a network failure).  As for the blocking-threads problem, I recommend using non blocking I/O instead, and if you need to block, block inside of select().  That way your thread can be woken up if necessary (either by a timeout or by sending it data on another socket)

Comment: ***Why*** can't the second thread send the CLOSE if the first one is reading? Any problem doing that is due to your own code. There's nothing in the API that prevents it.

Comment: Okay, this is excatly what I wanted to hear - now I know I have to find it in code.

Answer (score 0):

One way to attract the attention of a pthread which is blocked in `read()` or `write()` or `pselect` etc is pthread_kill(), which delivers a signal to a particular pthread.  The target pthread must be set up to catch your chosen "wake-up" signal (an empty signal handler will do) and not mask it.

**However**, there is a big problem here... you cannot tell whether the pthread is blocked, nor can you tell whether it is about to block, so the signal may be lost !  So, the next trick is to use non-blocking I/O and `pselect()` -- which, yes, does seem to defeat the purpose of having a pthread to get away from all that !  Now what you do is to mask the "wakeup" signal most of the time in the pthread.  But, when the pthread "goes to sleep" on a `pselect()`, you set the pselect to unmask the "wakeup" signal while it is waiting.  This arranges for the signal to be delivered, reliably.  When the pselect returns, you have to check for errors, in particular `EINTR`.

With `pselect()` you can also set up a dummy pipe, which you also wait on.  To attrach the pthread's attention, you write to the pipe.  I happen to prefer the signal method.